# When is onStartCommand of a service executed

Tags: android

When is onStartCommand of a service exactly executed?

In the following code my service is started from the onCreate in my activity

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CenseDroidService.class);
        //onStartCommand is not extecuted immediatly after startService
        startService(intent);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
```

So when does the Android system decide to call onStartCommand? All that I know is that is runs on the main thread some time after calling startService. The onCreate is fully executed before onStartCommand is called.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)).

> Called by the system every time a client explicitly starts the service by calling startService(Intent), providing the arguments it supplied and a unique integer token representing the start request

What this means is, every time you call `startService(intent)` with an Intent, then `onStartCommand` will be called.  If you have a hundred Activities that all need to start and bind to this service, then they will all call `startService()` and `onStartCommand` will be called.

Now when it is **exactly** called is a bit trickier to answer. It is sometime in the future which is why your `ServiceConnection` works asynchronously. Most likely it can be within the next UI Thread cycle, but it is not something you should rely on.

If you need a reasonable knowledge of when the `Service` started,  you could use the [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to broadcast the event to all registered listeners. The `LocalBroadcastManager#sendBroadcastSync` will actually block until all listeners respond so it may be useful for this scenario.